# Reverse one chart and leave the other unreversed - Synchronized highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

In order to reverse a chart you have to add `reversed: true`. It can be done either on the `xAxis` or the `yAxis`. In this example provided by [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts): https://jsfiddle.net/omaraziz/zg516ruk/ when I add reversed, it reverses all the charts. How can I reverse only one chart? More generally, what is the proper way to do more customization on one chart and not the other when the two are synchronized?
I chose synchronized because I wanted the values from both to be displayed at the same time when scanning from right to left and vice versa.

For now every time I change the legend position, reverse xAxis or yAxis, play with the tooltip, set a max and min for the yAxis, etc. it does it to both.

Here's my JSON data, in case the way to do it is through the JSON file: https://omaraziz.me/CC-chart/activity.json

Comment: Generally you configure only one chart, the reason your configuration options apply to all of them is because you are creating 3 charts with the same code, starting here ` activity.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {`. There are many ways to mitigate this, for example you could use `if` logic, and match on some element of the chart you want reversed. You could remove the loop and copy the code as many times as you have charts, then you could edit each chart before it is created. Or you could make an id for the charts that you later select and apply options to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use index variable `i` to recognize the chart. For example the IFFE function below return true only for the second chart:

```
            xAxis: {
                reversed: (function() {
                    return i === 1
                })(),
                ...
            }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7fx6jdnw/